# Could someone help debug or solve this?

Tags: swift, forms, swiftui

I'm building this app which lets you change the color of text resize it and customize it, however I am running into this problem, where it says this:

> Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure.

Edit:The error is on the 27th line

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    func openForm(){
        //hi
    }
    @State var x = 80.0
    @State var y = 1100.0
    @State var text = ""
    @State var fontSize = 1.0
    @State var color = Color.primary
    
    
    var body: some View {
            NavigationStack{
                VStack{
                    Text("Font Size:\(fontSize*20)").position(x: x, y: y)
                    Text(text).position(x:950,y:0).font(.system(size:fontSize*20)).foregroundColor(color)
                }.toolbar{
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement:ToolbarItemPlacement.bottomBar){
                        //Slider to change font Size
                        Slider(value: $fontSize, in: 1...7, step:1).frame(width: 300)
                        
                        //button to open form
                        Button(action:openForm){
                            NavigationLink("Add Text"){
                                Form{
                                    Section{
                                        TextField("Input text", text: $text)
                                    }
                                    Section{
                                        TextField("X position", value: x?)
                                    }
                                    Section{
                                        TextField("Y position", value:y?)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        //color picker
                        ColorPicker("ColorPicker", selection: $color)
                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is usually caused by a typo, comment out sections of code until you find the issue

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to check out https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Please create a descriptive title. [ask]

Comment: SO doesn't show line numbers. "The error is on the 27th line" doesn't help us. We would have to copy your code to a text editor that includes line numbers in order to tell which is the offending line. Can you quote the text of the line, and also add a comment like `// <--- This is the line that's giving the error" so we can tell which line it is?

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd and 3rd TextField objects inside the Form Sections are using the wrong overloads. Change them to be the following:

```
TextField("X Position", value: $x, formatter: NumberFormatter())

TextField("Y Position", value: $y, formatter: NumberFormatter())
```